# Position: sticky overlapping the subsequent container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble with `position: sticky`.

I have three boxes one after another. Each box has a class `container` of [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) The `box-2` is desired to be fixed. So, I used `position: sticky` for the `box-2`. Things seem good.

Working Version: https://jsfiddle.net/shr9d2t8/2/

However, when I actually use it in a real-world use-case with [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/), where each box contains `row` and a `col` nested boxes, then the `box-3` **contents overlap** over the box-2 while scrolling.

Problematic version: https://jsfiddle.net/vczmayf7/20/

What is going wrong?

Comment: increase the z-index of box-2 (bootstrap add position:relative to all the col elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After set `z-index: 100` to `.box-2` seems to work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/4bk19ao6/